# What's a more efficient way to make sure I'm not stuck in an infinite loop in this quicksort function? (C++)

Tags: c++, performance, infinite-loop, quicksort

Here is the relative part of my partition function:

```
    while(low < high){

      while(arr[low] < pivot)
         low += 1;

      while( arr[high] > pivot)
         high -= 1;

       people temp = arr[low];
       arr[low] = arr[high];
       arr[high] = temp;

       if(L==low && H==high)
         {low+=1; high -= 1;}
       L=low; H = high;
   }
```

I used L and H to see whether or not low or high changed at the end of the enclosing loop. Without them I may get stuck in a loop if I do not increment low or high, but at the same time I need to retest the value after a swap.

Comment: Not sure why you're doing it this way. You  can just always increment/decrement after the swap.

Comment: @JordiVermeulen I originally did that, but it only partly sorted the array. The "sorted" array would sometimes have items next to each other out of order. After my ghetto-rigging, the array is fully and properly sorted, but it takes roughly twenty percent longer to do so and I'm sure there's a better alternative.

Answer (score 0):

I think there are two problems with the code.

1. You do not consider the case when an element of the array is equal to the pivot.
2. You do not consider the case when `arr[low] > pivot` and `arr[high] < pivot` but
    `low >= high`.

See some partition code [here](https://www.cs.auckland.ac.nz/~jmor159/PLDS210/qsort1a.html).

Comment: I added a condition for my overloaded < operator so that it returns true if the two items are equal. I am getting a segfault now. After placing a break within the nested loops when low==high, I no longer have a segfault, but I'm back to where I started with a mostly sorted array.

Comment: What I meant to say is that you shouldn't swap when `low >= high`.